# Why Unknown custom element error using vuetable-2 component?

Tags: vuejs2, pagination

In @vue/cli 4.0.5 app adding https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2 component I got
error in the console:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <vuetable-pagination> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

My vue file is :

```
<template>
    <div class="test" style="width: 100% !important;">
        <h1>This is a test page</h1>


        <div class="ui container">
            <vuetable ref="vuetable"
                      api-url="https://vuetable.ratiw.net/api/users"
                      :fields="fields"
                      pagination-path=""
                      @vuetable:pagination-data="onPaginationData"
            >
            </vuetable>
            <vuetable-pagination ref="pagination"
                                 @vuetable-pagination:change-page="onChangePage"
            ></vuetable-pagination>
        </div>



    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Vue from 'vue'

    import Vuetable from 'vuetable-2/src/components/Vuetable'
    import VuetablePagination from "vuetable-2/src/components/VuetablePagination";


    Vue.use(Vuetable);

    export default {
        components: {
            'vuetable-pagination': Vuetable.VuetablePagination,
            Vuetable,
            VuetablePagination,
        },

        data() {
            return {
                fields: ['name', 'email','birthdate','nickname','gender','__slot:actions'],
            }
        }, // data () {


        methods: {
            onPaginationData (paginationData) {
                this.$refs.pagination.setPaginationData(paginationData)
            },

        }, // methods: {

    }
</script>
```

I suppose that I added VuetablePagination in import and component parts to my page, but 
looks invalid way?

Which way is valid to use this component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

Add Bootstrap

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Your Component vue

```
<template>
    <div class="app" style="width: 100% !important;">
        <h1>This is a test page</h1>


        <div class="ui container">
            <vuetable ref="vuetable"
                      api-url="https://vuetable.ratiw.net/api/users"
                      :css="css.table"
                      :fields="fields"
                      pagination-path=""
                      @vuetable:pagination-data="onPaginationData"
            >
            </vuetable>
            <vuetable-pagination ref="pagination"
                                 @vuetable-pagination:change-page="onChangePage"
                                 :css="css.pagination"
            ></vuetable-pagination>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Vue from 'vue'

    import Vuetable from 'vuetable-2/src/components/Vuetable'
    import VuetablePagination from "vuetable-2/src/components/VuetablePagination";


    Vue.use(Vuetable);

    export default {
        components: {
            Vuetable,
            VuetablePagination,
        },

        data() {
            return {
                fields: ['name', 'email','birthdate','nickname','gender','__slot:actions'],
                css: {
                    table: {
                        tableClass: 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hovered',
                        loadingClass: 'loading',
                        ascendingIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up',
                        descendingIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down',
                        handleIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger',
                    },
                    pagination: {
                        infoClass: 'pull-left',
                        wrapperClass: 'vuetable-pagination pull-right',
                        activeClass: 'btn-primary',
                        disabledClass: 'disabled',
                        pageClass: 'btn btn-border',
                        linkClass: 'btn btn-border',
                        icons: {
                        first: '',
                        prev: '',
                        next: '',
                        last: '',
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        }, // data () {


        methods: {
            onPaginationData (paginationData) {
                this.$refs.pagination.setPaginationData(paginationData)
            },
            onChangePage (page) {
                this.$refs.vuetable.changePage(page)
            }

        }, // methods: {

    }
</script>
```

Comment: That is bootstrap(not bootstrap-vue )app.
Actually in docs page I do not see any required refs to bootstrap / bootstrap-vue
I see this example :
https://codepen.io/ratiw/pen/GmJayw
looks like myne and do not see why it does not work for me

I have :
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "core-js": "^3.3.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    ...
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "vuetable-2": "^1.7.5"
?

Comment: Vuetable is trying to be CSS framework agnostic, but in your example settings it refers to Bootstrap3, you don't need to use BoostrapVue. The error is in the component part, it should be like this: components: {Vuetable,VuetablePagination }. I updated my answer, this example can help you https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2-tutorial/wiki/lesson-07